# Obtaining answers with site imposed stumbling blocks that stifle and prevent communication and feedback

Tags: discussion

So I'm having a problem with running neural network code presented in an online Python training course.  I've checked and double checked the code I've written/copied from the presentation, and it is verbatim to what the instructor presented.  I posed the question on Stack Exchange (I'm new, so forgive me for putting a question in the wrong place - I'm learning here).  I got a couple non-answers, more like questions and a request to see the code more fully.  During that exchange, StackExchange decided my question should be posted here on Cross Validated.  Shortly after that, Cross Validated closed the question because it did not fit the site's parameters, so now I'm back to ground zero and loosing confidence in the usefulness of this site.

If the site is not for Q&A between original posters and those trying to answer the question, then obtaining solutions to a question quickly come to a stand-still.

If the site reposts a question to another location, and that new location deems the question out of bounds for the location and shuts the question down, that kills any hope of obtaining a helpful answer.

How does one overcome these hurdles?

Comment: *"Cross Validated closed the question"* It is difficult to respond to this question without a reference to the closed question that it is about.

Comment: AFAIR, @SextusEmpiricus, that account had no question. So, it could be perceived this account was solely made to air the user's rant on the alleged experience.

Comment: Whether deliberately or accidentally, the OP made it impossible to discuss their case carefully, so this is, unfortunately. a fairly futile question. It's all too easy for one site to conclude that a question is too statistical and for us to decide that it is too code-based.  In fact on the little evidence here it seems just as likely that Stack Overflow [not Stack Exchange] rejected a question that should be theirs, so the complaint should be directed there (or there too). No disagreement that where to post a borderline question is a tricky issue, but the issue isn't best posed like this.

Comment: (+1); @NickCox Albeit being unfortunate and we never want any to get deprived of any constructive help, OP perhaps didn't have the intention (or might have lost their nerves due to back & forth movement without getting any answer) to have a healthy discussion. That's where Meta CV plays a powerful role: clear any impending confusion. We perhaps can never know what actually happened without checking the post in question. I believe we need to emphasize the importance of Meta to the new users in mitigating any such situation in the future. SO might have erred. But ranting is not the answer.

Comment: That’s my stance too. My comment starts with mentioning that omitting what we want to know might have been accidental.  That said, the OP comes across as smart enough to look at each site and get a good idea of how it works.  The cited request “to see the code more fully” is diagnostic of a problematic question on SO and in such cases (I am active there too) a question may be closed on various grounds; there is some caprice over which ground is most visible.

Answer (score 6):

A sense of frustration is reflected here. So, it deserves few explication:

- It is imperative for the community to seek clarification from OP - it enhances the chance of receiving a meaningful answer. As long as it remains ambiguous or there is dearth of research effort, that would be unsalvagable.
- Then comes how to ask a good question. Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Merely asking some programing fix wouldn't be tantamount to a good post, for example.
- Prior asking, it is apt to check the [scope](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site.
- A question is closed for [valid reason(s)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Once it is edited properly, then it would likely be reopened:

> Any closed question that receives one reopen vote by a user with sufficient reputation is automatically added to a reopen queue for community review. In addition, any question with significant edits that address the close reason(s) gets added to the reopen queue. If enough community members agree, the question will be reopened and can accept answers.

As it is evident, this is a community driven Q&A site and not a forum. Everyone is here to help others. So, while it might be daunting a bit, it's not a point of dilemma. If the community didn't deem the post provided ample clarity or the question is not within the scope or it still lacks sufficient research, then it would face necessary action(s). And in each phase, OP does have the ability to make their posts more concise and suitable, answerable for the site.

Answer (score 5):

That seems like a mistake by Stack Overflow. We shouldn’t be closing questions as “off-topic due to being coding questions” when they have been migrated from there.

In fact, I thought there was a way to block the migration or send it back, if Cross Validated (or any other Stack to which a question is migrated) deems the question to be off-topic.

I don’t see your question, so I cannot judge if it is a clear question that can result in useful answers, but debugging a piece of neural network code seems completely within the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: This seems reasonable to me, so why the downvote?